# jQuery: Manipulate prices in radio button list

Tags: jquery, each

Given is this unordered list:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" name="radio" id="product1" value="product1" checked="checked"><label for="product1"><span>Product 1</span></label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="radio" id="product2" value="product2"><label for="product2"><span>Product 2 [+ 10 $]</span></label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="radio" id="product3" value="product3"><label for="product3"><span>Product 3 [+ 20 $]</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

Now the additional prices should be relative. When you choose the second radio button, the additional price of Product 3 should be "[+ 10 $]" (the difference between 20 $ and 10 $). The "additional" price of Product 1 should be "[- 10 $]" (the difference between 0 $ and 10 $).

So the list should look like this after choosing the second radio button:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" name="radio" id="product1" value="product1" checked="checked"><label for="product1"><span>Product 1 [- 10 $]</span></label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="radio" id="product2" value="product2"><label for="product2"><span>Product 2</span></label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="radio" id="product3" value="product3"><label for="product3"><span>Product 3 [+ 10 $]</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

How can this be achieved using jQuery?

Comment: Can you post relative js code please?

Comment: **How can this be achieved using jQuery?**...this is not the way of asking question...just show us what you have tried so far????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my jsfiddle for the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/3m580heq/11/

I have added a `data-price` attribute to hold the price of the product

```
 <ul class="price-list">
      <li>
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="product1" data-price="100" value="product1" checked="checked">
          <label for="product1"><span>Product 1</span></label>
      </li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="radio" id="product2" data-price="110" value="product2"><label for="product2"><span>Product 2 [+ 10 $]</span></label></li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="radio" id="product3" data-price="120" value="product3"><label for="product3"><span>Product 3 [+ 20 $]</span></label></li>
    </ul>


$(function() {
    $('.price-list input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        var _radioObj = $(this);
        var _currentPrice = _radioObj.attr('data-price'); // or .data('price');

        $.each(_radioObj.closest('ul.price-list').find('input[type=radio]'), function() {
            var _span = $(this).parent('li').find('span');
            var _count = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price')) - parseFloat(_currentPrice);
            _count = _count > 0 ? '+ ' + _count : _count.toString().replace('-', '- ');
            var _newContent;

            if(_count == 0)
        {
            if(_span.html().indexOf('[') > 0)
                _span.html(_span.html().substring(0, _span.html().indexOf('[') - 1));           
           else
               _span.html(_span.html());  
        } else {
            if(_span.html().indexOf('[') > 0)
                _span.html(_span.html().substring(0, _span.html().indexOf('[') - 1) + ' [' + _count + ' $]');            
           else
               _span.html(_span.html() + ' [' + _count + ' $]');       
        }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the jsfiddle doesn't work. And I cannot add an attribute.

Comment: I see it it is working in firefox but not in chrome... Ah ok I will change that

Comment: Where do you hold the price then of your products?

Comment: Sorry, I can add the price attribute now.

Comment: Can you try it in firefox to see if its working there

Comment: In Firefox it works, only the plus signs are missing.

Comment: It is working in chrome now also see answer, + sign is also added

Comment: One question left: How to get a space between the minus sign and the price? I tried `count = count > 0 ? '+ ' + count : '- ' + Math.abs(count);`, but then "[- 0 $]" is displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with more than one `<ul class="price-list">...</ul>`. :(

Comment: Thank you. I have updated your jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/3m580heq/7/ Both `<ul class="price-list">...</ul>` should work independent.

Comment: Last thing: It doesn't work, when two or more products have the same price. See: http://jsfiddle.net/3m580heq/10/

Comment: Thank you! I think, it would be more robust, if the prices would be in their own span, because if the product name contains "[" it doesn't work properly anymore. What do you think? See (non working) jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3m580heq/15/